# Find all the SQL Servers in the network

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to find all the SQL Servers running in the network. I want it find it through a `tsql` query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future question, I suggest to add what you had try so far, and a specific question, like : I had try to find ...  and I found nothing, is it possible to do ...

Answer (score 2):

T-SQL/SQL is not about queryin the network it about querying a relational data bases. So I believe you've to use other approaches.

Useful links:

– [Find All Servers From Local Network using sqlcmd](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/18/sql-server-find-all-servers-from-local-network-using-sqlcmd/)